# Download all photos from part of a url in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, downloads, facebook, url

I want to download all photos from a Facebook post. I noticed that all photos are contained in links that share the following URL:

> https://www.facebook.com/photofbid=*&set=pcb.1491477148127430

with the "*" meaning that it's the only part of the URL that varies. What I would like to do is extract the jpeg in each link in that photo set. Is there a way to do it, for instance in the terminal?

> https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=122141748638087442&set=pcb.1491477148127430

For example, I'd like to download this photo and then find other link in that set with which to extract the next one.